# Samsung S2 not deleting sent emails on gmail

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, gmail, sync

I have a samsung s2 all other parts of the Gmail is syncing.  But in the sent items on my phone there are about 10 sent emails that are not on my online account (have deleted there) and when I try and delete from my phone they just keep reappearing and will not delete.

Help anyone want to clear them from my phone and not sure what is happening!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in the past with my Samsung Galaxy S Vibrant. What I did, and it solved my problem was:

1. Go in to `Settings -> Accounts & Sync`
2. Select the gmail account with issue
3. Turn off sync for Gmail
4. Turn back on sync for Gmail

If this doesn't fully solve the issue, but it did for me, try the following:

1. Go in to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications`
2. Select the All Tab
3. Find the Gmail Application and select it
4. Click on Clear Data and Clear Cache
5. If you have multiple accounts on the device, it may remove them from accounts and sync. At the very least, you will have to go back to accounts and sync to re-enable Gmail sync.

It really isn't that big of a deal to clear the Gmail data because it is all constantly sync'd with the Google servers. It will clear out any Gmail app settings you have set, like your signature on your phone if you set one.

Comment: That has worked in respect of the gmail App but they are still showing if look at the emails on the social hub....

Comment: Have applied this to the normal email as well and has worked and cleared everything, had to reset some things but not works better than before thanks